# How to re-apply $(document).ready() to some partial HTML loaded via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm still a jQuery newbie and I'm trying to integrate a ThemeForest template into my project. This ThemeForest template (vPanel) is awesome but it integrates a lot of jQuery plugins and features so I have a lot of $(document).ready() all over the place and I'm having a hard time figuring out  which script does what. The reason why I'm looking for that is because all those scripts apply nicely to the page when it is initially loaded, but there are also some parts of my UI that are loaded later via AJAX. And that's where my problem starts: is there a way to re-apply all of the scripts to the partial HTML that is loaded via AJAX?

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is the [live() event](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You may have to go back and change certain plugins so that things like

```
$("my_button").click(function(){ }
```

become

```
$("my_button").live("click", function(){ }
```

where "my_button" is something that could be later via AJAX.

Comment: Or even better, use delegate().

Comment: And there is no solution without modifying plugins? That would be insane, it looks like a very common use case!

Answer (score 0):

If all that the scripts does is hook up events, you can use the `delegate` method (which replaces the `live` method) to hook them up to a containing element instead.

If the scripts does other changes to the elements, then you would need to use a context parameter so that you can reapply the changes to a specific part of the page. Example:

```
function applyTemplate(context) {
  $('.someclass', context).each(function(){
    // does something with the elements
  });
}

$(function(){
  // apply to whole page:
  applyTemplate(document.body);
  // load more content, and apply to what's loaded:
  $('#somePart').load('getpart.aspx', function(){
    applyTemplate($('#somePart'));
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I wouldn't know how to implement the applyTemplate() function as the template is made up of a bunch of jquery plugin scripts loaded in the header. So I was more looking for a way to re-apply them all simply.